# Ionic full height list

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to make a full height list on Ionic, the list is not dynamic, it will always have 3 items, but I want to be sure it will be full screen on different screen sizes.
I tried with `height:100%`, but no luck, the idea is to do something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eotRc.png

Maybe using lists is a wrong approach, I lave a code here of a list example where i was trying to make full height: [List example code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvqZyj)

This is a good example of what I need, but this is on jquery mobile jsfiddle.net/gu7WE/1706/.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the height of each list element as such:

```
ion-item{
  height: 33vh;
}
```

From my understanding, setting a height in `vh` gives it a percentage of the viewport. So in theory, whatever the size of the screen is, each list item should be about a third of the screen.

Comment: Thank you, that looks to be working.
I couldn't find any documentation about this particular case, if you have a link with documentation, I will be grateful.